# Searching xlsx files in a folder and look for specific elements in all sheets

Tags: pandas, excel, search, openpyxl, return-value

I am trying to get values from all excel sheets in a given directory and search for the cell value next to a text. However, in the excel sheets I have those cell values are as formulas and I am having a hard time getting them.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def search_workbooks(folder_path, search_phrase):
    results = []
    
    # Iterate through all files in the folder
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
            
            # Load the workbook
            workbook = load_workbook(file_path, read_only=True)
            
            # Iterate through each sheet in the workbook
            for sheet_name in workbook.sheetnames:
                sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
                
                # Iterate through each row in the sheet
                for row in sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
                    # Search for the phrase in the row
                    if search_phrase in row:
                        phrase_index = row.index(search_phrase)
                        value = row[phrase_index + 1] if phrase_index + 1 < len(row) else None
                        value = str(value) if value is not None else ''
                        results.append((filename, sheet_name, search_phrase, value))
    
    # Create a DataFrame for the results
    results_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Workbook', 'Sheet', 'Phrase', 'Value'])
    
    return results_df


# Provide the folder path and search phrase
folder_path = 'PATH'
search_phrase = 'search phrase'

# Call the function to perform the search
search_results = search_workbooks(folder_path, search_phrase)

# Display the search results
print(search_results.head(50))
```

This is the code i wrote but when I run it, it finds all the cells where my search phrase exists, but it returns an empty value for the cell to its right.

Anyone can solve this issue for me?